# Creating Files And Saving Objects In Them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Why when you call this method (saveObject: (id)object forKey: (NSString *) key), will a file not get created???

When I call it filePath is equal to nil so the (-(void) setFilePath: (NSString *)fileName) method will get called...

```
-(int) saveObject: (id)object forKey: (NSString *) key {
    //save object into file

    if(filePath == nil) {
        [self setFilePath:nil];
    }

    mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if(mainDict == nil) {
        mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    [mainDict setObject:object forKey:key];

    if(![mainDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
        if(object == nil) {
            return 3;
        }
        if(key == nil) {
            return 4;
        }
        return 2; //ERROR could not write object to file
    } else {
        if(shouldUseCache == YES) {
            cacheStatus = 2; //New Caches need to be updated
        }
        return 1; //SUCCESS object saved to file
    }

    //RETURN KEY's
    // *1 SUCCESS object saved to file
    // *2 ERROR could not write object to file
    // *3 ERROR object variable = nil
    // *4 ERROR key variable = nil
}

-(void) setFilePath: (NSString *)fileName {
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    if(fileName == nil) {
        fileName = @"savedObjects";
    }
    filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",documentsDirectory, fileName];
}
```

Comment: Why do you tagged `[C]`?

Comment: You really need to look into memory management

Comment: @max_: why's that? If he's using ARC, everything seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the contents of the dictionary you are intending to write.
You are adding `object` to your dictionary.
That object must only contain members of types:NSArray , NSDictionary , NSString , NSDate, NSData and NSNumber. If your object contains a int or float , or anything other than these , it won't write.

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2)

Comment: Thanks guys I never remembered to alloc/init the objectSaver object